# Python Tkinter: Too many values?

Tags: python, exception, user-interface, tkinter

I got this error when I made it so that after the mouse button is released the text goes back to normal. If I comment out the code to bind this to mouse release and if I comment out the binding for mouse down.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File ".\gui.py", line 53, in button1Release
    self,button1["text"] = "Hello, World!"
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here is the code this came from:

```
#gui.py

import time
import tkinter

class GUI(object):

    #GUI.create()
    #loads interface
    def create (self, parent):

        #remember the root
        self.window = parent

        #simplify tkinter variables
        left = tkinter.LEFT
        right = tkinter.RIGHT

        self.container = tkinter.Frame(parent)
        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.container)
        #self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self.container)

        self.button1["text"]= "Hello, World!"
        self.button1["background"]= "white"
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1Click)
        self.button1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.button1Release)
        #self.button2["text"]= "Hello, World2!"
        #self.button2["background"]= "white"

        self.container.pack()
        self.button1.pack(side = left)
        #self.button2.pack(side = left)

        print("Window created")

    def run (self, parent):

        #mainloop

        parent.mainloop()

        #on window close

        print("WIndows closed!")
        time.sleep(1)

    def button1Click(self, event):

        self.button1["text"] = "Click!"

    def button1Release(self, event):

        self,button1["text"] = "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: What is your expectation and what have you got? Please make it clear to help others work on your problem.

Comment: Oh ok. I got the answer and I will work on clarifying next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote a `,` comma where you meant to use a `.` dot:

```
self,button1["text"] = "Hello, World!"
```

Note the comma between `self` and `button1`. It *should* be:

```
self.button1["text"] = "Hello, World!"
```

Python reads the first as two separate targets, requiring you to supply two values, one for `self` and one for `button1["text"]`.